# Firebase csv file auto uploader

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I started to learn to use firebase as the backend of flutter. The challenges that I have now is this:
I have a cvs file in an SFTP server (currently digital ocean) this file is from an external web application that exports the csv file once a day. I want to establish automatic sync between that csv file and my firebase database. How is that possible:
1- Can I use a firebase or Google cloud platform as an SFTP server instead of digital ocean?
2- Can I have a script that runs automatically once a day to convert the csv file and update the firebase database accordingly?

Thank you all for helping me on this!

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question per post. I tried to answer #1 below. For #2, have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only places to run your own code on Google's servers within Firebase is on Cloud Functions, and maybe Cloud Run. Neither of those allows you to open the ports that are required for SFTP though, so you won't be able to run an SFTP server on them.

You can of course set up a server on something like Compute Engine, App Engine, or Kubernetes engine, which are all similar to your current set up at Digital Ocean in that they allow you to run whatever you want on instances that you more-or-less manage yourself.